# Does the count query ignore sorting in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm just wondering, if I do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`, does MySQL sort the records before counting? Or does it understand that it makes no sense in this case and just ignores `ORDER BY`?

Comment: no it does not...

Comment: If you just need the count then what is the purpose of Order By here ?

Comment: When i look at [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wD2zsuTnvKM1qGtePXmzfU/0) the MySQL optimizer is smart enough to remove the ORDER BY in these cases the note shows me this

Comment: @AmitVerma we are using the query builder in java and we have a base query to get the data with `LIMIT` but before that we get the total amount of records. And I'm wondering should we remove the `ORDER BY` from that base query to run `COUNT` query. As I see it's not required.

Comment: @StanislauListratsenka for getting total count, order by is not required.

Comment: @AmitVerma I know. I meant our implementation is a bit complicated to do ORDER BY removal from COUNT query. And I was wondering if it's worth wasting time removing ORDER BY from count to increase performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` statement, is (in this query) the last statement to be executed.
The `ORDER BY` statement only afects the result, never affects the data you are looking into, so in this case the system will work in this way:

1. Count the rows that meet your condition (maybe using an index or a full scan, depending on the data and the conditions).
2. Get the rows for your answer, in this case just 1 row.
3. Try to order the rows of your answer, in this case with no effect because you have only one row.

So the order by (in this case) will have no effect, because the order applies only to the rows of the answer and you only have 1 row. And as someone said, it doesn´t make any sense to try to order a result with just one row.

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer your question with what I know, but I'm not sure if it will help you, if my answer is wrong, I hope you can point it out.

I am using the InnoDB engine of mysql. **InnoDB** cannot maintain a row_count variable like MyISAM, so when performing the **count(*)** operation, a full table scan must be performed, but it does not need to be as system-intensive as the **select *** operation Resources, but you know, after some calls from the relatively top-level sub_select function, all branches will eventually be called into the row_search_mvcc function, which is used to read a row from the **B+-tree** structure stored by the InnoDB storage engine to memory In one of the buf (uchar * ), it will be used for subsequent processing. Locks, MVCC, etc. may be involved here, but row locks **are not involved**. This is for reading a row of data in mysql, but it does not need to read a whole row of valid data. At the **code level**, it will be in evaluate_join_record The lines read are evaluated in the function. So, in my opinion, whether you use **order by** or not has little effect on **count(*)**.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to your specific question, it is not ignored nor optimized by the DB engine.
Performance is affected by # of rows not the # of keys.

Maybe you can find further info here

[ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)